# Difference between Random forest vs Bagging in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I know that Random forest uses Bagging, but how does ensemble give a single prediction in `sklearn` Bagging vs Random forest?
Also, I do not understand why in Bagging you not need to choose a tree estimator, while not in RF? 
other than this, are the other steps the same?
wht are main implementation differences in `sklearn` Bagging vs Random forest?

bonus points if you have "explain like I'm 5 years old" simple example using `sklearn` please.

Comment: How many 5-year-olds write python scripts?

Comment: Yeah, I did not understand that either. I kinda went with the spirit of what I thought he was asking. I think my answer is actually more 12-year-old-ish :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

we can use ["Iris" dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) to demonstrate both *Bagging* and *Random Forests*

first, Let's take a look at the *Iris* dataset:

- 150 *samples* of flowers
- 3 classes $y$
- 4 continuous features $x_j$

to do example in  `sklearn`, we need to import the usual suspects...

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd


iris = load_iris()
y= pd.Series(iris.target)
```

then we specify which of two ML models we will be using:

```
# create Ensemble object/instance
model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None)
model = RandomForestClassifier()
```

regardless of which of the 2 we use, our `sklearn` steps will be the same:

```
# Train the model using the training sets 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# OUTPUT
## check score
model.score(X_train, y_train)

## Predict on test set
predicted= model.predict(X_test)
```

---

In order to visually and fully  demonstrate the Bagging voting<sup>†</sup>, WLOG we have a simplified version "Iris" dataset has:

- 7 total observations *only*<sup>◊</sup>
- 4 features $\mathbf{x}_j$
- 3 different possible species as the labels $y$

  - instead of their Latin names, lets for simplicity denote the 3 different species as

    - Species $\mathbf{A})$
    - Species $\mathbf{B})$
    - Species $\mathbf{C})$
  - because `sklearn` needs numeric input always, their `sklearn` numeric labels $= [0, 1, 2]$

    - Species $\mathbf{A}) \mapsto 0$
    - Species $\mathbf{B})\mapsto 1$
    - Species $\mathbf{C})\mapsto 2$

[image]

---

`for` our 7-observation simplified "Iris" *Training* dataset, we:

1. **Take** 5 Bootstrap-samples

   - each Bootstrap-sample is of cardinality 7 selected WITH replacement from our simplified "Iris" dataset

     - i.e., each bootstrap-sample has 7 observations WITH possible Repetitions

then in step 2, we **Train** either:

- **Train** a distinct decision tree classifier on each of the Bootstrap-samples

  - each tree is fit on its own distinct Bootstrap-sample of 7 observations
- **Train** a distinct Random Forests decision tree classifier on each of the Bootstrap-samples

  - **Set** each Random Forests classifier to decision its tree node using *only* 3 of the 4 features $\mathbf{x}_j$

    - the 3 features selected are a random **subset** of the 4 possible features $\mathbf{x}_j$

      - (*subset* are drawn withOUT replacement)

so we end up with a Bootstrap-samples-aggregated ensemble of a total of 5 decision trees classifiers, which are either fully-grown in the case of Bagging or grown using feature subsets in the case of Random Forests.

3. **Predict** new data labels using  Bootstrap-samples-aggregated ensemble meta-estimator

   - Random Forests & other Bagging meta-estimators use *all* the 5 decision trees to predict the label $y$
   - all 5 trees predict and RF meta-estimator **averages** their individual predictions

     - (see example calculation below)

---

`for` a Test-set *X_test* consisting of a single previously-unseen  flower:

`if` the $(A, B, C)$  `predict_proba` output of the 5 individual `sklearn` subestimator trees are:

1. $(0.75, 0.20, 0.05)$
2. $(0.60, 0.35, 0.05)$
3. $(0.55, 0.40, 0.05)$
4. $(0.35, 0.60, 0.05)$
5. $(0.50, 0.45, 0.05)$

then either of the Bootstrap-samples-aggregating meta-estimators' Test-set `predict =` **`A)`** on this specific flower-sample

- i.e., our new Test-set observation would be classified as Species **`A)`** by either the Bagging or Random Forests meta-estimator
- because the highest of the 3 classes' **average** predicted probability is for Species $\mathbf{A}) = \frac{3 \, = \sum bootstraps \,}{5 \; bootstraps} = 0.55$
- because all of `sklearn`'s Bootstrap-samples-aggregating **classification** meta-estimators have a [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.predict) method whose averaging procedure `returns` the class with the highest **average** predicted probability

<sup>†<sub>(and also to be able to use an image i found on the [interwebs](https://cdn-ak2.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/r/robonchu/20171029/20171029181324.png))</sub></sup>

<sup>◊<sub>this (ridiculous) 7-datapoint"Iris" data set is for explanation purposes *only*</sub></sup>

Comment: Yes this is what I want.  Essentially the difference between the two Sci-kit-learn models

Comment: Btw I did not downvote you

Comment: +1 Tried to up vote your answer,  but I do not have enough points to do it.

Comment: No worries. Please let me know if anything is unclear in my explanation/example.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is at the node level splitting for both. So Bagging algorithm using a decision tree would use all the features to decide the best split. On the other hand, the trees built in Random forest use a random subset of the features at every node, to decide the best split.